# How to pass a list of values into Lambda environment variables with Terraform

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-ses

I have a Python script that sends an email to multiple recipients. I'd like to set up my recipients with Terraform and pass them into my Lambda function as environment variables. I have set up SES as separate module.

Lambda function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    email_to = os.environ["EMAIL"]
    # script that sends an email is here
```

Lambda module main.tf:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  filename      = var.filename
  function_name = "test_name"
  role          = "arn:aws:iam::123:role/lambda_role"
  handler       = var.handler

  source_code_hash = var.source_code_hash
  runtime = var.runtime
  timeout = var.timeout
  kms_key_arn = var.kms_key_arn
  memory_size = var.memory

  dynamic "environment" {
    for_each = var.env_variables != null ? var.env_variables[*] : []
    content {
      variables = environment.value
    }
  }

}
```

SES module main.tf:

```
resource "aws_ses_email_identity" "email" {
    email = var.email
}
```

SES module outputs.tf:

```
 output "email" {
    description = "Emails."
    value       = aws_ses_email_identity.email.email
    }
```

main.tf

```
module "lambda_zip" {
    source                = "../modules/lambda_zip"
    handler               = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
    runtime               = "python3.8"
    filename              = "setup.zip"

    env_variables = {
     EMAIL = module.ses[*].email
   }
}

module "ses" {
    source      = "../modules/ses"
    for_each    = toset(["email1@example.com", "email2@example.com"])
    email       = each.value
}

output "email" {  
value = module.ses.email 
}
```

With the current setup I get this error:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 24, in module "lambda_zip":
│   24:    EMAIL = jsonencode(module.ses[*].email)
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "email".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 40, in output "email":
│   40:   value = module.ses.email
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.ses is object with 2 attributes
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "email".
```

How can I register new emails with SES and also pass them into the Python function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass all emails at once, it it should be:

```
    env_variables = {
     EMAIL = jsonencode(values(module.ses)[*].email)
   }
```

In your function then, you have to process the EMAIL as json data structure.

Comment: This gives me `This object does not have an attribute named "email".`

Comment: @Omega So how do you output emails from `module.ses`? You have to explicitly define an `output`.

Comment: Still nothing with my outputs.tf looking like this `output "email" {description = "Emails."value= aws_ses_email_identity.email.email}`

Comment: @Omega I updated the answer. If it still does not work, you have to provide full code of your module in question.

Comment: I'm still running into the same issue and have updated my original post with the script of the lambda module

Comment: Its not possible to obtain error ""each.value" has been used in a context in which it unavailable, " with your `module "lambda_zip`. If the error comes from a different resource, then new question should be made.

Comment: No, the error is `This object does not have an attribute named "email".` based on your suggestion.

Comment: @Omega I don't see how that would be possible. Please provide full error msg, indicating exactly the line it occurs and the code it refers to.

Comment: Updated with question with the full error message.

Comment: Omega Can you try with `jsonencode(values(module.ses)[*].email)`?

Comment: That worked and I also had to change the output in main.tf to `output "email" {value =module.ses}` (essentially removing .email)

Comment: @Omega Glad it work out. If so, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated. I already edited it.